# How to prevent TabControl from switching tabs when Button is pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a new WPF (.NET Framework 4.7.2) application with a Window XAML defined as below:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab">
                <ToolBarTray>
                    <ToolBar>
                        <Button>Button</Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab">
                <ToolBarTray>
                    <ToolBar>
                        <Button>Button</Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp5
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now follow the steps below:

1. Run the app and switch to the second Tab
2. Switch back to the first Tab and press Button

This makes the TabControl switch to the second Tab for no apparent reason as seen here:

[image: Tab switching]

Can someone elighten me why this happens and how to fix it so it does not switch the tab on a Button press, please?

Many thanks!

---

Related Links:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2278

Comment: It is a bug introduced from `.Net version 4.7.1`, I have tested your code in `.Net version 4.6.2` which does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A good enough soluton for me was to set x:Name on the TabControl and set FocusManager.FocusedElement to the TabControl name:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="300"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tabControl}">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
            <TabItem Header="Tab">
                <ToolBarTray>
                    <ToolBar>
                        <Button>Button</Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab">
                <ToolBarTray>
                    <ToolBar>
                        <Button>Button</Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Still got no idea why this happens though so it's not a perfect answer.